# How can I get the number bytes to write per row for FrameBuffer?

Tags: display, images, framebuffer, fbi

**Goal**: I'm writing a very simple image viewer for framebuffer `/dev/fb0` (something like [fbi](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fbi)).

**Current state:**

1. My software takes the pixel resolution from `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size` (such as `1920,1080`).
2. And then (for each row) it will write 4 bytes (BGRA) for each 1920 row-pixels (total 4x1920=7680 bytes) to `/dev/fb0`.
   This works perfectly fine on my one laptop with a 1920x1080 resolution.
3. More precisely: setting a pixel at `y`-row `x`-col => `arr[y * 1920 * 4  + x * 4 + channel]` where the value `channel` is `0,1,2,3` (for `B`, `G`, `R`, and `A`,  respectively).

**Problem**:

When I try the same software on my old laptop with (`/sys/.../virtual_size` -> `1366,768` resolution), the image is not shown correctly (bit skewed). So I played around the pixel-width value and found out the value was **1376** (not 1366).

**Questions**:

1. Where do these 10 extra bytes come from?
2. And, how can I get this value of 10 extra bytes on different machines (automatically, not manually tuning it)?
3. Why do some machines need these extra 10 bytes, when some machines don't need them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Programmatically, to retrieve information about a framebuffer you should use [the `FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO` and `FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO` `ioctl`s](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fb/api.html#screen-information):

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct fb_fix_screeninfo fix;
  struct fb_var_screeninfo var;

  int fb = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
  if (fb < 0) {
    perror("Opening fb0");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (ioctl(fb, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &fix) != 0) {
    perror("FSCREENINFO");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (ioctl(fb, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &var) != 0) {
    perror("VSCREENINFO");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Line length: %ld\n", fix.line_length);
  printf("Visible resolution: %ldx%ld\n", var.xres, var.yres);
  printf("Virtual resolution: %ldx%ld\n", var.xres_virtual, var.yres_virtual);
}
```

`line_length` gives you the line stride.

Comment: I'm amazed there's a specific ioctl for that!

Comment: @MarcusMüller ioctls are specific to the type of device. Almost every device has a bunch of very specific ioctls you've never heard of. Every device feature that isn't a read or write or mmap is an ioctl.

Comment: @user253751 I'm somewhat painfully aware of the wealth of ioctls in Linux, it's just that these are properties I would have expected to be well enough represented through the sysfs API to the kernel

Comment: @MarcusMüller sysfs tells you generally about the things in the system; ioctl tells you about the thing you have open right now. Imagine needing to reverse-engineer the name of your framebuffer then go and open it in sysfs that may or may not be mounted. (Some APIs *are* like that and that's terrible)

Comment: I see that point, especially since fb might be useful quite early in userland booting

Answer (score 9):

The row *stride* does not have to be the same as the *width*; on your 1920-wide screen your software just worked "by accident" (not much of an accident, strides are typically chosen for hardware alignment requirements, and 1920 is already divisible by 16, which is a common alignment requirement).

Not being familiar with the good ole Linux framebuffer infrastructure, I can't directly tell you how to do it, but you will need to figure out the stride.

Either Linux just documents that rows are aligned by multiples of 16, do that you always need to round up your width to the next multiple of that, or /sys/class/graphics/fb0/ contains a different virtual file that defined the stride, or the row alignment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems the stride value can be extracted from `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/stride`. Do you know why it's need to be multiples of 16 (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: It boils down to various hardware elements (the graphics card's memory units, the DMA controller used to transfer data between RAM and GPU, and the CPU SIMD units used to calculate pixels) having needs for addresses to be "simple"; when something is 16 bit aligned, you can just worked with the fifth bit upwards.